# Sentence structure with adjectives/adverbs

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Kindly consider the following sentence.

> She sat bored at the edge of a cliff.

I have a few issues while identifying its structure. I can see `sat` is a verb; therefore, it's starting with `S+V`.

The next word `bored` is either an `adjective` or an `adverb`. I'm not sure. **Can I get some help here?**

Lastly, `at the edge of a cliff` is a prepositional phrase, which is working as an `adverb`.

Overall, the structure might be `S + V + C + C` but not so sure.
(`Subject + Verb + Adjective + Adjective Complement`)

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Why not two adverbs?

Comment: "Bored" is an adjective here functioning as a predicative adjunct. It's predicative because it refers to a predicand, "she", and an adjunct because it is an optional modifier in clause structure, i.e. it's part of the predicate verb phrase, not part of the NP subject. "At the edge of a cliff" is a PP functioning as an adjunct of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence the verb 'sat' is used not only as an action verb but also as a link verb.
The real semantics of the sentence can be structured like this: 'She was bored, and she sat ...'
So in this sentence 'bored' is an adjective and functions as the predicative.

Comment: Oh, then the prepositional phrase `at the edge of a cliff` has nothing to do with the adjective `bored`. It is actually an `adverb` referring to the verb `sat`. Looks I get this! Thank you so much :)